# Transaction Replication with new schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema, transactional-replication

I am trying to create Transaction Replication on SQL server 2008 R2.

The subscriber database will be new and we need to set new schema for it, meaning we want to have "NewSchema"."TableName" rather than dbo.tableName.

I have created new database and created new schema and choose this new schema value while creating the replication i.e "Destination Object Owner" for all tables.

After saving the value is again set to default, I read that it is default behaviour of SQL server.

But the problem is when I see the synchronization status it says
"The concurrent snapshot for publication 'xxxx' is not available because it has not been fully generated or the Log Reader Agent is not running to activate it. If generation of the concurrent snapshot was interrupted, the Snapshot Agent for"

The Snapshot is complete and Log reader agent also look fine.

Can you please help me in this!

I think the because of the security/permissions of new schema its failing.
Because earlier with default schema replication worked perfectly fine.

Please can you let me know the steps to follow for this, creating schema, permissions for it and then for replication.

Regards,
Arvind

Answer (score 0):

Here is minimal permissions required for Snapshot, Log Reader and Distribution Agents:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868(v=sql.105).aspx

You can check the logs, use Replication Monitor and Profiler to find out what's going on and what is missing. It's hard to tell you what to change when we don't have access to your system.